# Fastest way to chop array in two pieces

Tags: c#, performance, unmanaged

I have an array, say:

```
var arr1 = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

Now, when my array-size exceeds 5, I want to resize the current array to 3, and create a new array that contains the upper 3 values, so after this action:

```
arr1 = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };
newArr = new [] { 4, 5, 6 };
```

What's the fastest way to do this? I guess I'll have to look into the unmanaged corner, but no clue.

---

Some more info:

- The arrays have to be able to size up without large performance hits
- The arrays will only contain Int32's
- Purpose of the array is to group the numbers in my source array without having to sort the whole list

In short: I want to split the following input array:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 29, 31, 33, 35, 36, 37 };
```

into

```
arr1 =  1, 3, 4
arr2 =  29, 31, 33, 35, 36, 37
```

but because the ideal speed is reached with an array size of 3, `arr2` should be split into 2 evenly sized arrays.

**Note**

I know that an array's implementation in memory is quite naive (well, at least it is in C, where you can manipulate the count of items in the array so the array resizes). Also that there is a `memory move` function somewhere in the Win32 API. So I guess this would be the fastest:

1. Change `arr1` so it only contains 3 items
2. Create new array `arr2` with size 3
3. Memmove the bytes that aren't in `arr1` anymore into `arr2`

Comment: just curious, what's your end goal for this? Why do you want the array split as such?

Comment: @townsean: random guess: splitting nodes in an n-ary tree. (But in that case I wouldn't create two arrays of size 3, but one of size 6 and maintain an element counter.)

Comment: Let's say I have 300.000 different pointers I want to read. They are divided over 700 MB of memory, but they are clustered into around 100 clusters; so I don't want to read all that memory to find the value the pointers point to. I chop the addresses into (max.) 16 MB chunks and read each chunk.

Comment: @Jan Jongboom: But two split something large into two something small, you already need to have the large thing in memory, no? Unnecessarily copying large amounts of memory around doesn't exactly speed up things. Or are those 700MB on your hard-drive and you want to read the file in 16MB chunks into memory?

Comment: @Jan: How are you reading these to start with? Is there any reason you can't create the arrays as you go?

Comment: The array is a list of pointers that I gather from reading another processes memory.

Comment: Does the data structure have to be an *array*? Can you tell us more about what operations you're going to perform on the data? For example, an immutable catenable deque implemented with finger trees has pretty fast "split" and "join" operations and can maintain pretty good data locality for short subsequences, but it is expensive to get an element out of the middle of a long one.

Comment: @Eric: An "immutable catenable deque implemented with finger trees" also wins CompSci buzzword bingo, earning you free beer and pizza until you next break the build ;)

Comment: @Jon: That's why it's my favourite data structure.

Comment: @Eric: that sounds like a data structure from the world of "Alice in Wonderland" lol.

Comment: So I'm confused. The array is six items long, or three hundred thousand items long? You are splitting it into hunks of three, or hunks of several thousand?  Can you describe the real problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure there's anything better than creating the empty arrays, and then using [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx). I'd at least *hope* that's optimized internally :)

```
int[] firstChunk = new int[3];
int[] secondChunk = new int[3];
Array.Copy(arr1, 0, firstChunk, 0, 3);
Array.Copy(arr1, 3, secondChunk, 0, 3);
```

To be honest, for very small arrays the overhead of the method call may be greater than just explicitly assigning the elements - but I assume that in reality you'll be using slightly bigger ones :)

You might also consider *not* actually splitting the array, but instead using [`ArraySegment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) to have separate "chunks" of the array. Or perhaps use `List<T>` to start with... it's hard to know without a bit more context.

If speed is *really* critical, then unmanaged code using pointers may well be the fastest approach - but I would definitely check whether you really need to go there before venturing into unsafe code.

Comment: wow...never heard of an ArraySegment. That's interesting, I'll have to check that out. >.>

Comment: Presumably this is going to be done to keep an array from getting too large, so an `ArraySegment` is probably not the right tool.

Comment: Yeah, know about the ArraySegments, yet my new array should have the ability to size up and down; and in that case have to edit the segment every time. The two array's shouldn't know about each other after splitting.

Comment: @Jan: Do you need to be able to remove items as well? Giving more information in the question would really help. (Your comment in the question bit is a start, but not very concrete in terms of requirements.)

Comment: Every time someone mentions `ArraySegment` I despair for what could have been... Why must you be so stupid, ArraySegment?

Comment: My experiments with `Array.Copy` have shown it to be rediculously fast. I now use it whenever possible, even in places where it is not at all appropriate, just because it’s so dang fast. :-) (I also love it for the ability to copy within a single array—even overlapping ranges—with no worries.)

Comment: `ArraySegment`, on the other hand, is terrible (just as @recursive says). It is just a leaked implementation detail. Nothing to see there.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
static unsafe void DoIt(int* ptr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ptr[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(ptr[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(ptr[2]);
}

static unsafe void Main()
{
    var bytes = new byte[1024];
    new Random().NextBytes(bytes);

    fixed (byte* p = bytes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += sizeof(int))
        {
            DoIt((int*)(p + i));
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This avoids creating new arrays (which *cannot* be resized, not even with unsafe code!) entirely and just passes a pointer into the array to some method which reads the first three integers.

Answer (score 2):

If your array will always contain 6 items how about:

```
var newarr1 = new []{oldarr[0], oldarr[1],oldarr[2]};
var newarr2 = new []{oldarr[3], oldarr[4],oldarr[5]};
```

Reading from memory is fast.

Comment: +1: This is probably going to be the fastest approach - much faster than using LINQ, at least.  Sometimes, the obvious answer is nice :)

Comment: @Reed thanks, it's not necessarily elegant, but provided the domain of the problem is fixed(size of array not changing) then it makes sense.  We'll see if my answer outduels the great John Skeet.

Comment: Still fact that you are creating two new arrays whilst there already is one.

Comment: @Jan Not true, I'm creating references to already referenced memory.

Comment: @Jan Jongboom: You can't resize arrays. If you have an array of size 6 and want two arrays of size 3, there is no other way than creating two arrays of size 3. "Resizing" an array refers to the procedure of creating a new array, copying all elements and discarding the old array. In performance critical applications it's best to avoid unnecessary array resizing, e.g., by creating an array of the maximum size and keeping a counter of elements actually used.

Comment: Hmm, don't agree there. An array is something in-memory like 'count of objects', 4 * count bytes of data. Don't know about C# here tho, but by changing the 'count of objects' bytes you should be able to really 'resize' the array.

Comment: @Jan: Every approach will create 2 new arrays.  LINQ, however, will create two iterators THEN two arrays, so the LINQ solutions will be far less efficient....

Comment: @Jan Jongboom: C#/.NET doesn't allow you to change the size of an array after it has been created. Sorry if this contradicts your opinion. :-)

Comment: When you instantiate an array in C#, it simply sets aside that many addresses as pointers to objects in memory. Even if the object pointed to does not exist, the pointer to the object is still there.

Comment: Check my edit (and now there are more than 15 chars in this box)

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays are not dynamically resized in C#, this means your first array must have a minimum length of 5 or maximum length of 6, depending on your implementation. Then, you're going to have to dynamically create new statically sized arrays of 3 each time you need to split. Only after each split will your array items be in their natural order unless you make each new array a length of 5 or 6 as well and only add to the most recent. This approach means that each new array will have 2-3 extra pointers as well.

Unless you have a known number of items to go into your array BEFORE compiling the application, you're also going to have to have some form of holder for your dynamically created arrays, meaning you're going to have to have an array of arrays (a jagged array). Since your jagged array is also statically sized, you'll need to be able to dynamically recreate and resize it as each new dynamically created array is instantiated.

I'd say copying the items into the new array is the least of your worries here. You're looking at some pretty big performance hits as well as the array size(s) grow.

---

UPDATE: So, if this were absolutely required of me...

```
public class MyArrayClass
{
    private int[][] _master = new int[10][];
    private int[] _current = new int[3];
    private int _currentCount, _masterCount;

    public void Add(int number)
    {
        _current[_currentCount] = number;
        _currentCount += 1;
        if (_currentCount == _current.Length)
        {
            Array.Copy(_current,0,_master[_masterCount],0,3);
            _currentCount = 0;
            _current = new int[3];
            _masterCount += 1;
            if (_masterCount == _master.Length)
            {
                int[][] newMaster = new int[_master.Length + 10][];
                Array.Copy(_master, 0, newMaster, 0, _master.Length);
                _master = newMaster;
            }
        }
    }

    public int[][] GetMyArray()
    {
        return _master;
    }

    public int[] GetMinorArray(int index)
    {
        return _master[index];
    }

    public int GetItem(int MasterIndex, int MinorIndex)
    {
        return _master[MasterIndex][MinorIndex];
    }
}
```

Note: This probably isn't perfect code, it's a horrible way to implement things, and I would NEVER do this in production code.

Answer (score -1):

The obligatory LINQ solution:

```
if(arr1.Length > 5)
{
   var newArr = arr1.Skip(arr1.Length / 2).ToArray();
   arr1 = arr1.Take(arr1.Length / 2).ToArray();
}
```

LINQ is faster than you might think; this will basically be limited by the Framework's ability to spin through an IEnumerable (which on an array is pretty darn fast). This should execute in roughly linear time, and can accept any initial size of arr1.

Comment: Lovely as LINQ is, it's not going to be the *fastest* approach :)

Comment: True, but in the case of arrays it'll be a *fast* approach. Array.Copy would be faster, though, as the memory allocation behind the scenes would be in a big chunk; fewer roundtrips.

Comment: This won't work. The array's `Length` property will always be the size which was given to it upon instantiation, regardless of the number of real objects currently pointed to.

Comment: Sure it will. The result of ToArray() is a totally new instance of an array; arr1 is simply a reference to an array on the heap, and that reference does not, by itself, keep track of how big an array it originally pointed to. The Array, as a reference object on the stack, does that.

Comment: @KeithS - That's not what I was referring to. The `if (arr1.Length > 5)` won't work. If you make a `int[] arr1 = new int[6]` and never put anything in it, it's `Length` will still be 6.

Comment: @md5sum: ... and the responsibility for making sure the array actually got populated is outside the scope of this algorithm. Array.Copy() on an empty int[6] would get you two empty int[3]s. You gonna vote that one down?